# Surface area of the circle

Tags: integration, circles, polar-coordinates

I was told to calculate the surface area of the following circle by the integration method (monte carlo)

$x^2 + y^2 = 1$

The area of this circle is determined by the following inequalities:
$-1 ≤ x ≤ 1$ and $ -\sqrt{1 − x^2} ≤ y ≤ \sqrt{1 − x^2}$.

Should I change the circle equation to the polar coordinates?

(exponentiation fixed)

Comment: A circle has no area, but a disk has.

Comment: Uhm, what is the meaning of the $\pi*r^2$ equation then...?

Comment: @Spenser There are more than 350,000 entries in google under "circle's area" I think it is correct as most people understand the meaning.

Comment: @Timbuc The OP is asking about a numerical approximation, Monte Carlo integration, and is only asking whether a transformation of coordinates is a better way to proceed.

Comment: @Beginnerinfort The expression $\pi \cdot r^2$ contains no 'equals' sign, so it is *not* an equation...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An idea with polar coordinates:

$$\int_{-1}^1\int_{-\sqrt{1-x^2}}^{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dydx=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^1rdrd\theta=\left.2\pi\frac{r^2}2\right|_0^1=\pi$$

Of course, the above is just the area of a circle of radius $\;1\;$ , as proposed in your question. If you want a circle with radius $\;R\;$ just change accordingly $\;-R\le x\le R\;$ .

Comment: That was the answer I have been looking for :)